# Accessing custom SAML attributes in WSO2 Api manager mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured WSO2 Api Manager to work with WSO2 Identity Server which acts as SAML2 identity provider (application API calls are authenticated by Identity Server). On the Identity Server side I have also added custom claim handler which adds some additional information about the user. I see that custom attribute is included in the SAML2 response so up to this point everything seems to work correctly.

However I have problems accessing custom attribute value in the WSO2 API Manager message mediator (written in Java). I don't see this value available in the MessageContext object. In AuthenticationContext I see various user-related information but no custom attributes. Is it possible for message mediator to access custom attributes contained in SAML2 response?